# iOS app stalls and uses 100% CPU for a couple of seconds using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nspredicate

Hi I was wondering if you guys could help me figure how to prevent my app from stalling and using 100% CPU:

Basically the is filtering the feed to items that contain specific strings, when it's just a couple of strings it's checking against then it's fine however when it's 4+ then it stalls, more strings to check against to longer it stalls. How can I optimise this better?

I've attempted to hide it behind a loading icon but it stalls before the loading icon.

Anymore information needed please let me know. Thanks

Code

```
if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        NSLog(@"RELOADED SEGMENTED");
        //NSArray *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favTeams"];

        if(favFilters.count > 0){
            //[subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleTeam IN %@", favFilters]];
            for(NSString *text in favFilters){
                //[subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleText CONTAINS[c] %@",text]];
                [subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rumourToTag.tagName =[cd] %@",text]];
            }
            predFav = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredsOr];

        }

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }

    if(subPredsOr.count > 0)
        [subPreds addObject:predFav];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPreds];

    NSLog(@"Pred: %@", pred);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];
    if(![self.isFav boolValue])
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:70];
```

**[EDIT]**Full method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Rumour" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    if ([self.isComps boolValue]) {
        NSError *errorb;
        NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errorb];


        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        }
    }

    NSPredicate *p;

//    #if defined(FRLITE)
//    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isLite == 1) AND (isAndroid == 0)"];
//    #else
//    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isLitePromo == 0) AND (isAndroid == 0)"];
//    #endif

    NSMutableArray *subPreds = [NSMutableArray array];
    //[subPreds addObject:p];

    NSMutableArray *subPredsOr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSPredicate *predFav;

    if([self.isNews boolValue]){
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rumourToTag.tagName =[cd] 'news'"];
        [subPreds addObject:p];
    }

    if([self.isVirals boolValue]){
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rumourToTag.tagName =[cd] 'virals'"];
        [subPreds addObject:p];
    }

    if([self.isComps boolValue]){
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rumourToTag.tagName =[cd] 'competitions'"];
        [subPreds addObject:p];
    }


    if([self.isPopular boolValue]){
        NSPredicate *p;
        if([self.popularSelector isEqualToString:@"popularDay"]){
            p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPopularDay == 1"];
        }
        if([self.popularSelector isEqualToString:@"popularWeek"]){
            p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPopularWeek == 1"];
        }
        [subPreds addObject:p];
    }

    if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        NSLog(@"RELOADED SEGMENTED");
        //NSArray *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favTeams"];

        if(favFilters.count > 0){
            //[subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleTeam IN %@", favFilters]];
            for(NSString *text in favFilters){
                //[subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleText CONTAINS[c] %@",text]];
                [subPredsOr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rumourToTag.tagName =[cd] %@",text]];
            }
            predFav = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredsOr];

        }

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }

    if(subPredsOr.count > 0)
        [subPreds addObject:predFav];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPreds];

    NSLog(@"Pred: %@", pred);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];
    if(![self.isFav boolValue])
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:70];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    if([self.isPopular boolValue])
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.popularSelector ascending:YES];
    else
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"articleDate" ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".

    NSString *sectionKeyPath = @"customSectionTitle";
    if([self.isPopular boolValue])
        sectionKeyPath = nil;

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyPath cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    if (self.view.window){

        if([__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].count < 10){
            if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 || [self.isEuro boolValue]){
                //Ricco[self performSelector:@selector(getMoreStories)];
                //Ricco[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading Rumours..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
            }
        }

        if([__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].count == 0){
            if([self.isPopular boolValue])
                [self popularRefresh];
            if([self.isVirals boolValue])
                [self viralsRefresh];
        }

    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Have you try to profile your app using time profiler? Also, post a complete method will help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I don't know what time profiling is but I'll look into it. I have updated my question with the full method as well. Thanks

Comment: You can follow the first part of this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode to profile so that you can find out which method actually takes up your cpu. It is actually quite straight forward and help pinpoint your problem.